# Align summation with capital letters inline

Tags: inline

I imagine this has been asked, but everything I can find when searching is about aligning with line breaks, or messing with limits.  Also searching for centering summation, naturally has its own commands it gets lost in. I have also seen the `\displaymath` option, but this breaks the spacing of the inline text.  I just want the sigma to align with the letter.

[image]

Comment: Symbol for summation (or for product) is deliberately designed. that it appears as you shown. Compare it with letter `\sigma` which hasnt features of symbol `\sum`. See `\documentclass[margin=1mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\begin{document}
ons $\left[ V(t) = \Sigma_{i=0}^n \sum_{i=0}^n V_i, Ce \Pi\prod_{x}^{n} \right]$

\[ \left[ V(t) = \Sigma_{i=0}^n \sum_{i=0}^n V_i, Ce \Pi\prod_{x}^{n}\right] \]
\end{document}`

Comment: You might be able to use the letter `\Sigma`, or failing that, measure the heights and depths of both letters and scale them to the correct ratio with a `\scalebox`.

Comment: Does your document feature both `\Sigma` and `\sum`?

Comment: @Davislor `\Sigma` was aligned, but made them the same size, based on the way `\scalebox` seems to work, this did what I needed `$\scalebox{1.2}{$\sum$}V$`

Comment: Another way to align them without changing the size would be to put them in a `\raisebox` by their depth.

Comment: @Davislor ah! that is beautiful `$(V_t)$ \raisebox{.2ex}{$=\sum$}$V$` aligns everything nicely. Thanks for both methods (if you put in an answer ill accept it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what precisely you want, you have several options.  You can raise symbols to the baseline by measuring their depth and putting them in a `\raisebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\pagestyle{empty}

\newlength{\symboldepth}
\newcommand\atbaseline[1]%
  {\settodepth{\symboldepth}{\(#1\)}%
   \raisebox{\symboldepth}{\(#1\)}}
   
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  (V_t) &= \mathop{\atbaseline{\displaystyle\sum}}
           \atbaseline{\displaystyle V}, \dots \\
  (V_t) &= \mathop{\atbaseline{\textstyle\sum}}
           \atbaseline{\textstyle V}, \dots \\
  (V_t) &= \mathop{\atbaseline{\scriptstyle\sum}}
           \atbaseline{\scriptstyle V}, \dots
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample]

Putting the operator in a `\raisebox` would normally change the class to `\mathord`, so you need to wrap it in `\mathop` to restore the proper spacing.  You might also try the letter `\mathrm\Sigma`, which is normally close in size to V, instead of `\sum`.

Comment: just as a note for others looking, the operators you listed solve the issue, but the example output is just showing the extreme from my original intention of just having them centered. It can be customized.

Comment: @001001 I was not perfectly clear on what exactly you wanted, but it’s possible to vertically center any symbol with `\vcenter`.